# CSS Background color with image

Tags: css, background-image, background-color

I have a background image and below that I want to have a color.

I have this CSS:

```css
body {
    background: url('/images/background.jpg');
    background-color: #000;
}
```

But the image appears with no color. I've also tried this:

```css
body {
    background: #000 url('/images/background.jpg');
}
```

But that doesn't work either. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does your background image actually have any transparency where your CSS background color could show through? Could you provide a live example?

Comment: Since it's a JPG image there isn't even support for transparency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you really want? The background color around the image background or in the back of the image? If it's in the back of the image you have to use an .png (transparent) image and the `background: #000 url('/images/background.png');`

Answer (score 0):

```
background: #000 url('/images/background.jpg');
```

Comment: I tried your code and it didnt work, the background image appears but no color

Comment: The line is evaluated the same way as the two lines in the start post.

Answer (score 0):

Your background color is actually working but it is being overlapped by declaring a background-image. Unless your image supports transparency like .png and opacity was declared. You would be able to view your bg-color.

It will help if you provide us your exact image and the output you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Use in this way `background: #657b78 url('../images/background.jpg') repeat top left;`. Do not forget to check if the URL of such image is correct.